# ButtonClicker example. Landscape disabled

Tags: google-play-games

I've modified the GAMEPLAY SCREEN with a SurfaceView (I created a class for the SurfaceView based off of the LunarLander example and I see the black canvas when I navigate to GAMEPLAY SCREEN):

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                <!-- INVITATION POPUP -->
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/invitation_popup" style="@style/InvPopup">
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/incoming_invitation_text" style="@style/InvPopupText" />
                    <Button android:id="@+id/button_accept_popup_invitation"
                        style="@style/InvPopupButton"
                        android:text="@string/accept_popup_invite" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- "PLEASE WAIT" SCREEN -->
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/screen_wait" style="@style/LLScreen">
                    <TextView style="@style/Blurb" android:text="@string/please_wait" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- GAMEPLAY SCREEN -->
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/screen_game" style="@style/LLScreen">
                    <com.ecsbackgammon.BackgammonBoardView 
                        android:id="@+id/bbview"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
```

I'm noticing about the ButtonClicker example that there is something about the code that is preventing the activity from entering landscape mode when the device is physically turned. So it seems that the gyroscope is
being ignored. I have a feeling that this has something to do with the fact that the Activity's class is derived from BaseGameActivity although I am not yet sure what to look for that might be preventing landscape mode from occurring.
So the Activity is derived in the ButtonClicker example like:

```
            public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity
                    implements View.OnClickListener, RealTimeMessageReceivedListener,
                    RoomStatusUpdateListener, RoomUpdateListener, OnInvitationReceivedListener {
```

So in the application all the LinearLayouts are hidden and only one at a time is made visible as the user navigates the activity. So my question is this about landscape mode. Is there a way to enable landscape mode only
when GAMEPLAY SCREEN is the active view? What is preventing landscape mode? In fact I think in the case of my application that it would be beneficial to disable portrait mode only when GAMEPLAY SCREEN is the active view.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for you most likely is that you haven't changed the android:screenorientation for the activity in the androidmanifest for the example.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.example.games.bc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The fact that the ButtonClicker2000 example locks it to portrait by default is the issue.  You probably want it to be:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```